# Calculating Daily Stock Drawdowns in SQL

Tags: sql, stocks

I have a table of stock prices, from which I'd like to calculate drawdowns.

```
Ticker       Date        price
ABC         01/01/13    100.00
ABC         01/02/13    101.50
ABC         01/03/13     99.80
ABC         01/04/13     95.50
ABC         01/05/13     78.00
XYZ         01/01/13     11.50
XYZ         01/02/13     12.10
XYZ         01/03/13     13.15
XYZ         01/04/13     14.10
XYZ         01/05/13     15.55
```

I'm defining drawdown as the difference between the max price (up to and including that date) minus the current price divided by the max price.

Here's what the daily max price and daily drawdown should look like:

```
Ticker   Date       price      max   drawdown
ABC     01/01/13   100.00    100.00    0.0%
ABC     01/02/13   101.50    101.50    0.0%
ABC     01/03/13    99.80    101.50    1.7%
ABC     01/04/13    95.50    101.50    5.9%
ABC     01/05/13    78.00    101.50   23.2% 
XYZ     01/01/13    11.50     11.50    0.0%
XYZ     01/02/13    12.10     12.10    0.0%
XYZ     01/03/13    13.15     17.15    0.0%
XYZ     01/04/13    14.10     14.10   17.8%
XYZ     01/05/13    15.55     15.55    9.3%
```

I know how to calculate one max drawdown for an entire dataset, but am struggling to refine that apply to individual stocks and be a daily drawdown.

```
;WITH x AS
(  SELECT [drop] = ((s.price-e.price)/s.price) *100 
    FROM [temp] AS s
    INNER JOIN [temp] AS e
    ON s.[Date] < e.[Date]
    AND s.price > e.price
)
   SELECT [Largest Drawdown] = MAX([drop]) FROM x;

Largest Drawdown
87.900000000000000
```

This drawdown is calculating the max price for the entire dataset (ABC of 101.50) and the low from the dataset (XYZ = 11.50) to get its largest drawdown of 87.9%

How do I calculate daily drawdowns for each stock?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(t.price) over (partition by ticker order by date) as max_price,
       (t.price / max(t.price) over (partition by ticker order by date)) - 1 as ratio
from temp t;
```

Comment: @Coding_Newbie . . . When an answer meets your needs, you should consider accepting it.